# Room TypeConverter with Dagger in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dagger-2, typeconverter

Does anyone know a way to add a type converter to room database using dagger2. My application throws an error that the type converter is missing from the database configuration. Here is my code:

DatabaseModule

```
@Module
object DatabaseModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(applicationContext: MobileApplication): LocalRoomDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, LocalRoomDatabase::class.java, "local_database")
            .addTypeConverter(DateTimeConverter::class)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDao(database: LocalRoomDatabase) = database.roomDao()
}
```

LocalRoomDatabase

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(IND1::class, STT4::class, UNT1::class, USR1::class, WHS1::class), version = 2)
@TypeConverters(DateTimeConverter::class )
abstract class LocalRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun roomDao(): RoomDao
}
```

DateTimeConverter

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class DateTimeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDate(dateString: String): LocalDateTime? {
        return if (dateString == null) {
            null
        } else {
            LocalDateTime.parse(dateString)
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDateString(date: LocalDateTime): String? {
        return if (date == null) null else date.toString()
    }
}
```

How to correctly inject a type converter using dagger2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding your type converter with `addTypeConverter`, you're required to provide an *instance of your converter*, not the class reference. So you should be doing something like this:

```
addTypeConverter(DateTimeConverter())
```

However here it doesn't look like you need to inject your type converter in the first place, if it's not necessary you can just get rid of the `ProvidedTypeConverter` annotation and the `addTypeConverter` call.